# My javascript doesn't work on my html code

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to make Mortgage calculator. But I don't know what is the problem, and so it doesn't works. Can you guys notice me what is the problem?

here is my code for html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Mortgage calculator</title>
   
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
   <script src="assignment1.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
   <header>
      <h1>
         Mortgage calculator
      </h1>
   </header>

   <article>
      <h2><br></h2>
      <form>
        <fieldset>
        <label>
        Mortgage Amount: $
             <input type="number" id="MA" name="MA" required>
   </label>

        <label>
        Down Payment Option: 
         <input name="pickone" type="radio" id="5" onclick="document.getElementById('amor').value = '25';" required>5%
         <input name="pickone" type="radio" id="10" onclick="document.getElementById('amor').value = '25';" required>10%
         <input name="pickone" type="radio" id="15" onclick="document.getElementById('amor').value = '25';" required>15%
         <input name="pickone" type="radio" id="20" onclick="document.getElementById('amor').value = '30';" required>20%
        </label>     
         
        <label>
        Down Payment: $
         <input type="number" id="DP" name="DP" required>
    </label>
    
        <label>
        Amortization: 
         <input type="text" id="amor" name="amor" required> years
        </label>  
      
        <label>
        Interest Rate: 
         <input type="number" id="IR" name="IR" required>%
        </label>
       
   <button type="button" id="button">Calculate</button>

   <label>
   Result: 
    <input type="number" name="Result" id="Result">
   </label>
   
   </fieldset>
   </form>
   </article>    
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my assignment1.js file

```js
 function calculate() {
     var mortamount = document.getElementById("MA").value;
     var downpayment = document.getElementById("DP").value;
     var amortization = document.getElementById("amor").value;
     var interest = document.getElementById("IR").value;
     
    
     var p = mortamount - downpayment;
     var n = amortization * 12;
     var r = interest / 100 / 12;
     var 1R = 1 + r;
     
     
     var top = r * p * Math.pow(1r,n);
     var bot = Math.pow(1r,n) - 1;
     
     var mpay = top / bot;
     
     document.getElementById("Result").value = mpay;
 }
 document.getElementById("button").
 addEventListener("click", calculate, false);
```

thanks for helping :)

Comment: Where is it breaking? What have you tried?

Comment: Your javascript is loading and trying to find `document.getElementById("button")` before the DOM has even begun loading

Comment: `it doesn't works` - that's obvious because you wouldn't ask the question if it worked. Debugging 101: check the browser developer tools console for errors

Comment: Variable names should not start with a number i.e `1R`. Then you also try to reference it by using 1r.

Comment: thanks guys !! I'm the beginner of these code things so I couldn't really find what is the problem. maybe I should try to fix again. Really thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check the developer console for errors... `var 1R`, variable names can't begin with a number.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and the line 11, 1R seems like causing some problem. Variable names shouldn't be starting with number. (also it has 1R, and then later 1r so I think you need to clear the variable names first.) Then, like other people commented, the javascript file is loaded first and is looking for button which is not loaded yet. So you need to put something like below in your js file.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
// your code goes here
}
```